# Can sssd-ldap authenticate non-posix users?

Tags: pam, sssd

I am migrating a sealed MSA from using `pam_ldap` to `pam_sss` (sssd-ldap). However, pam_sss seems to have having trouble authenticating users without `uidNumbers`. I had thought changing  `ldap_user_object_class` from `posixAccount` to `top` would fix this, but it has not. Users with uidNumbers seem to be fine. While it is to be expected that sssd would require uidNumbers for `nss`, I do not see why they would be necessary for `pam`.

syslog facility auth:

```
Aug  6 11:23:03 centos7-msa-test saslauthd[644]: pam_sss(smtp:auth): received for user non-posix-user: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)

# cat /etc/pam.d/smtp
#%PAM-1.0
auth    sufficient  pam_sss.so
account sufficient  pam_sss.so

# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = pam
domains = example.com-ldap
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
[domain/example.com-ldap]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.example.com, _srv_
ldap_user_object_class = top
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
ldap_user_search_base = ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?onelevel?
ldap_group_search_base = ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com?onelevel?
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

$ ldapsearch -ZZ -h ldap.example.com -b ou=users,dc=example,dc=com -s one"(&(uid=non-posix-user)(objectClass=top))"
dn: uid=non-posix-user
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: inetLocalMailRecipient
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: uidObject
cn: non-posix-user
mailLocalAddress: non-posix-user@example.com
mailRoutingAddress: non-posix-users@example.com
mailHost: mailstore.example.com
roleOccupant: uid=posixuser1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
roleOccupant: uid=posixuser2,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
userPassword:: e1NBU0x9bm9uLXBvc2l4LXVzZXJARVhBTVBMRS5DT00K
uid: non-posix-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, SSSD only handles system users, that is, users with IDs. The ID can either be defined in LDAP directly or derived from SID.

Your use-case is not supported by SSSD at the moment, sorry.